# Where is this "{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}" found? (it is at the end of the Order Confirmation Email template)

Tags: magento-1.9, order-confirmation

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

I go into System --) Transactional Emails

and

I find the **new_order Template**. I am trying to **change the font size** (what is the best way to do that anyway? I am currently working with the h1-h5 tags...Is it possible to use the *font tag* in there also?)

At the bottom of this temple is the following code:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

I assume this is what throws the "Thank you, storename.com!" message there in really big letters? Where can I change this? (make it smaller font)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}`  the path for the footer file is

> app/locale/your_langauage/template/email/html/footer.html

For any css related changes  you can add your style rules in below file

> skin/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/scss/email-inline.scss

Comment: Piyush: Thank you Piyush. When I go into app/design/ - I have the following 3 choices: adminhtml, frontend and install...I tried to search in all 3 of those but I'm not finding any of the folders there....

Comment: sorry for the typo, it was `app/locale` check my updated answer, if you don't find it in your custom theme, it will be there in default theme

Comment: Piyush: That's it - thank you! In there - it says: h5 class="closing-text"...Would you know where that class is?

Comment: Please check in this file -
 skin/frontend/your_package/your_theme/scss/email-inline.scss

Comment: @Piyush How to change H5 tag inside the app/locale/your_langauage/template/email/html/footer.html based on a website in a multistore website, if website id ==1 tag should be <h5> else <h4> how to do this?